# Save DateTimePicker value

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

How can I fix this error? I can't save this value:

[image: visual]

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string rut = textRut.Text;
    string nombres = textNombres.Text;
    string paterno = textPaterno.Text;
    string materno = textMaterno.Text;
    DateTimePicker nacimiento = dateTimePicker1;
    DateTimePicker muerte = dateTimePicker2;
    string causa = causaText.Text;
    int cliente = int.Parse(comboCliente.Text);
    int enterrador = int.Parse(comboEnterrador.Text);
    int derecho = int.Parse(comboDerecho.Text);

    difuntoTableAdapter1.AgregarDifunto(rut, nombres, paterno, materno, nacimiento, muerte, causa, enterrador, cliente, derecho);
    this.difuntoTableAdapter1.FillBy(this.cementerioDataSet1.difunto);
}
```

The type of both `nacimiento` and `muerte` in DB is `date`. How can I save that type of data in DB from DateTimePicker?

[image: this is the error]

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to save it is

```
difuntoTableAdapter1.AgregarDifunto(rut, nombres, paterno, materno, nacimiento.Value, muerte.Value,causa,enterrador,cliente,derecho);
```

But the error message implies that the AgregarDifunto is expecting a string parameter here, not a date. This is in disagreement with your claim that this parameter relates to a date in the database. To resolve this we need to see the table definition and the query behind the AgregarDifunto method, possibly also some screenshots of the tableadapter query and its parameter set

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct type...

```
    DateTime nacimiento = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    DateTime muerte = dateTimePicker2.Value;
```

and edit the file cementerioDataSetDesigner, AgregarDifunto Method.